# Add conditional formatting onto colored cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

IS there any way I can add slashes through conditional formatting onto a colored cell. Like is it possible to keep the color of the cell but just add the pattern conditional formatting based on certain cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In your conditional formatting, set the *Background Color* to "No Color" and set the *Pattern Style* to the slash pattern.

[image: Format Cells dialog]

I was able to apply this to a blue cell and the cell remained blue underneath the pattern.

[image]